# How do I make three condition in pine script IF

Tags: pine-script

How would I make a code where I can see three different conditions, instead of only two? like IF and ELSE? Or could I make the code with these two? Thank you!.

Wrong code V

CrossoverPoint = color.white

```
if CrossoverPoint[0] > CrossoverPoint[1] 
    CrossoverPoint := color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 10)

if CrossoverPoint[0] = CrossoverPoint[1]
    CrossoverPoint := color.rgb(128, 128, 128, 10)

if CrossoverPoint[0] < CrossoverPoint[1]
    CrossoverPoint := color.rgb(0, 0, 255, 10)
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure on what you want to do. Do you want to combine all those three if statements into one?

Comment: Yes. I could only do two actions with only two conditions with this:

if CrossoverPoint[0] > CrossoverPoint[1] 
    CrossoverPoint := color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 10)

else 
    CrossoverPoint := color.rgb(128, 128, 128, 10)

I want to expand the else code to give me different color.rgb for < and = instead of lumping them together.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Ternary Conditional](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_%7Bquestion%7D%7Bcolon%7D)

Something like that:

```
CrossoverPointColor = 
  CrossoverPoint[0] > CrossoverPoint[1] ? color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 10) :
  CrossoverPoint[0] = CrossoverPoint[1] ? color.rgb(128, 128, 128, 10) : color.rgb(0, 0, 255, 10)
```